# npm install or yarn commands, are taking too long to run (Ubuntu)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, yarnpkg

I recently installed ubuntu and when I ran the command to install the dependencies of a project (npm install / yarn) it took 30 minutes to run. What can it be?

Comment: often if you have dependencies that need `node-gyp`, they need to compile whole modules/bindings if there are no prebuilt binaries available for your system+node version. Try removing unused dependencies and consider upgrading to a newer nodejs version

Comment: I'm using version 5.8.0 of npm

Comment: I am referring to the node version and not npm. but 5.8.0 is quite an old version of npm and means you are also using an old version of node with an old node-gyp. try upgrading to a newer node version

Comment: node  - version 13.8.0

Comment: when using node 13.8.0 you should also have npm 6.13.6. try `npm install -g npm`

Comment: Updated! The delay persists.

Comment: I believe it is a bug in the project, I created a new project, deleted node_modules and ran the npm install command, it ran normally!

Comment: yes, if you don't have any dependencies on the new project (inside package.json) there is nothing to install and thus, will be fast

Answer (score -1):

Firstly Check your internet connection

and close your all apt process using this command (sudo apt-get clean)
and then  try with your installations

Comment: My connection is normal, I have a speed of 500mb. In windows it was extremely fast, in linux it has this delay.

Comment: Same issue  is also with then i tried this link your should be fixed https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/